# problem with inherits and src attributes of page directive

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am having a problem with the page directive. The code behind file is CodeBehind.cs within the namespace **aspnetian**.

when i specify the inherit and src attribute like...

```
<%@ Page Language= "C#" src="~/CodeBehind.cs" inherits="aspnetian.CodeBehind.cs" %>
```

Parser Error Message: The base type 'aspnetian.CodeBehind.cs' does not exist in the source file '~/CodeBehind.cs'.

If I remove the namespace and specify the directive like...

```
<%@ Page Language= "C#" src="~/CodeBehind.cs" inherits="CodeBehind.cs" %>
```

it gives this error:

```
class 'codeBehind' and namespace 'CodeBehind', declared in 'D:\AspPractice\WebApplication1\WebApplication1\codeBehind.aspx.designer.vb', conflict in namespace 'WebApplication1'. D:\AspPractice\WebApplication1
\WebApplication1\codeBehind.aspx.vb
```

Please tell me where I am mistaken and whats the correct way.

Comment: You have two files in your program with same names,(CodeBehind) that is the reason for the conflict, Change your C sharp file name to CsharpCb.cs and for your first error , note that you don't need to enter namespace in page attribute .

Answer (score 1):

The inherits property should be describing the class the Page will use. I'm assuming the class you created looks like so:

```
public class CodeBehind : public Page
{
    // blah...
}
```

If that is the case then you just need to drop the .cs from the end of the inherits property.

Comment: GavinW...thanks. it worked. i dont know how i missed out that its the class and not the file which has to be mentioned

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" CodeFile="CodeBehind.cs" Inherits="aspnetian.CodeBehind" %>
```

Comment: Matthew...Gavin's solution proved fruitful. But i tried your solution as well but it dint work.